# Rails UJS for dynamically added content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, ujs

I am using Rails 3.0 with prototype ujs rails.js script.

I have some `link_to "...", :remote => true` links that are being added to the page after the page has loaded, and so after `rails.js` has attached the ujs events to all the `a[data-remote]` links.

How do I get rails.js to rescan for new links?

rails.js seems to consist of one anonymous function, so I can't call it directly.

The only way I can think of to do this is to wrap all of rails.js in my own function that I can then call on page load *and* when I've added new links.

This seems a reasonable approach, but I hesitate as I can't believe that I'm the first one to have this issue and that there isn't a standard way to do it...

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?  I'm having the same problem.  I am using `button_to` in the meantime which makes me sad.  I don't understand it because it is using `delegate` which is supposed to provide late binding.  Also delegate has been superceded..but that's another matter.

Answer (score 2):

When you are rendering a button, link, etc. you use the rails helpers

```
= link_to "Add to basket", basket_path, :method => :post, :remote => true
```

So you in the response of your remote view (ex.: **some_view.js.erb / some_view.js.haml**) you  should use again the rails helpers if you want a **:remote** element. 
You don't need to rescan them the new DOM elements so the remote behavior to be attached.

In the js view you can update/replace content from the DOM using javascript

```
:plain
        $('#some-id-selector').replaceWith("#{escape_javascript(render :partial => 'some_other_view.html.haml')}");
```

Also you can watch in the Network Inspector of your browser if the new actions is being send.

Answer (score 1):

You can call Rails "remote" link processing by your own. For example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.load-ad-node', function() {
  $.rails.handleRemote($(this));
  return false;
});
```